# simplify $3x^2 \times x^2 + x^3 \times 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Looking at an old assignment, and the function in the title is a derivative result of the product rule, but I've simplified it to $5x^4$, but I have forgotten how I got to that result. Anyone with a step by step solution?

Comment: I suggest you to write out the given equation for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$(3x^2)x^2+x^3(2x)=3x^{2+2}+2x^{3+1}=3x^4+2x^4=5x^4$